# Transformations using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an object I want to apply some transformations (translation) . I'm using the glTranslatef()  functions  .How can make it by using matrix I know how do it but as programming I don't know do it.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried so far. Consider posting code, the result you are getting and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Matrices in OpenGL are represented as one dimensional arrays of length 16 (4x4) in column-major order. See [chapter 3 of the OpenGL Red Book, section "General-Purpose Transformation Commands"](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html).

OpenGL has function `glMultMatrix{f,d}()` to multiply the current matrix stack by a new matrix. This is how you pre-multiply your current matrix by a new one. Note that matrices are applied in the reverse order compared to the function calls, for example:

```
glMultMatrixf(m3);
glMultMatrixf(m2);
glMultMatrixf(m1);

// Results in:   M = m3 x m2 x m1
```

Finally, your call to `glTranslatef()` is equivalent to this:

```
// Simple macro to compute the offset in the 1-D column-major ordered array
#define GLMATRIX(m, row, col) m[col*4+row]

float matrix [16];

// Identity matrix
std::fill (matrix, matrix+16, 0);
GLMATRIX(matrix, 0, 0) = 1;
GLMATRIX(matrix, 1, 1) = 1;
GLMATRIX(matrix, 2, 2) = 1;
GLMATRIX(matrix, 3, 3) = 1;

// Translation
GLMATRIX(matrix, 0, 3) = translationX;
GLMATRIX(matrix, 1, 3) = translationY;
GLMATRIX(matrix, 2, 3) = translationZ;

// Multiply matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // I assume you want to translate objects in your
                            // 3D scene so you need to be modelview mode
glLoadIdentity();           // And set the modelview stack to identity to
                            // apply your translation from the origin
glMultMatrix(matrix);       // Apply your translation now

// Draw stuffs
```

Comment: Nope, matrices are applied in the reverse order of the calls. `m1` first, then `m2`, then `m3`. The sequence of calls result in the concatenated matrix `M = m3 x m2 x m1`